# xamarin Essentials: No overload for > 'OnMainDisplayInfoChanged' matches delegate > 'EventHandler<DisplayInfoChangedEventArgs>'

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I am following a Xamarin Example with my code:

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfoChanged += OnMainDisplayInfoChanged;
    }

    void OnMainDisplayInfoChanged(DisplayInfoChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var displayInfo = e.DisplayInfo;
    }
```

As far as I can see this is just the same as in this example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-display?context=xamarin%2Fios&tabs=uwp

But it is giving me the error message:

> App.xaml.cs(13,13): Error CS0123: No overload for
>   'OnMainDisplayInfoChanged' matches delegate
>   'EventHandler' (CS0123)

Can anyone help explain to me what this error message means and let me know if there is a way for me to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is coming because you missing first `param` that is `object sender`. Try to pass full method signature.

```
private void OnMainDisplayInfoChanged(object sender, DisplayInfoChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var displayInfo = e.DisplayInfo;
}
```

Comment: thanks, looks like the xamarin documentation also has that error.